# Decoding Windows-1252 characters in imap subject line to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a website that will allow people to post things to it using the subject line of an email in Outlook. Using PHP and imap, I get the subject line of the text and store it in a mysql db. But every once in a while, someone will copy text from a website into the subject line of that email and I will get garbled text. Similar to this:

=?Windows-1252?Q?_Every_day_in_our_offices_we_recycle_cardboard,*aluminum?=
=?Windows-1252?Q?*=96_won=92t_you_join_us=3F?=

What I've done is try to decode this text so it will appear normal on the page using the following code:

```
$subject = strip_tags($mailHeader->subject);
$header = imap_mime_header_decode($subject);
$subject = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
{
    $subject .= $header[$i]->text;
}
```

When finished I get rid of most of the garbled text, but am left behind with replacement characters for an em dash and a curly quote that was in the original subject line text. See the result below:

Every day in our offices we recycle cardboard, aluminum, � won�t you join us?

The charset for the website is set to UTF-8. When I set the website charset to ISO-8859-1, the replacement characters are replaced with the curly quote and em dash, which is great but I want to leave the website's charset at UTF-8.

Any help on how to get rid of the replacement characters without changing the charset to ISO-8859-1 would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the objects returned by `imap_mime_header_decode` includes a `charset` property, which you are ignoring. You would need to convert each one to UTF-8 in your loop, using something like:

```
$subject .= mb_convert_encoding($header[$i]->text, "UTF-8", $header[$i]->charset);
```

As an alternative, consider using the [`mb_decode_mimeheader`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-decode-mimeheader.php) or [`iconv_mime_decode_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode-headers.php) functions. Both of these functions do the entire job of decoding a MIME header for you, returning a string in PHP's internal encoding (which is usually UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect. There was a small edit needed to be made in the code you posted. I'll post it below in case someone else stumbles across this some day.

Answer (score 1):

Code above works except for one small change to the very end:

```
$subject .= mb_convert_encoding($header[$i]->text, "UTF-8", $header[$i]->charset);
```

Comment: I've incorporated your fix into my answer.